# Excel macro to sort multiple columns of a selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want a macro to sort by the same two columns of a selected range. (Columns B and H)

The range might be limited to A1 to H40 in the VBA but I would want the code to show the range A to H in case the number of rows vary.

The sort would also have to be done on all columns A to H rather than B1 to B40 and H1 to H40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Sorting columns A to H you could use the below

```
Columns("A:H").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B:B"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H:H"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:H")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

All you needed to do was record the macro when you ran it and remove the row numbers, for example Range("B2:B20") to Range("B:B")

Answer (score 0):

```
`   
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H:H") _
, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J:J") _
, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
.SetRange Selection
.Header = xlGuess
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
`
```

Comment: This is sorting on the wrong columns